# Add/Remove value to input on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this code that i use, and on click i put email in field, but what i want to accomplish is that on next click on same field it removes email if one already exist in input.

Here is my code:

```
<p class="email">mail1@gmail.com</p>
    <p class="email">something@gmail.com</p>
    <p class="email">third@gmail.com</p>
<input type="text" id="contact-email" value="" class="form-control" style="width:500px" />
```

And js:

```
var $contact = $('#contact-email');
$('.email').on('click', function () {
    if ($contact.val()) {
        $contact.val($contact.val() +'; '+ $(this).text());
    } else {
        $contact.val($(this).text());
    }
});
```

and fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2dffwew5/2/

Comment: Then set it to an empty value, ie `''`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would store selected email addresses to an array. Then push or splice the clicked email.

```
var $contact = $('#contact-email');
var emails = [];

$('.email').on('click', function () {
    var index = emails.indexOf($(this).text());
    if (index > -1) {
        emails.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
        emails.push($(this).text());
    }
    $contact.val(emails.join(";"));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jdgiotta/ze7zebzq/

Comment: Yep, this is much better than my suggestion. Much more reliable

Comment: Ah my mistake, you wanted the click on the `$contact` to remove. Text positioning...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you add a check to see if the current text *contains* the selected email address. If it does, then remove it. Otherwise add it.

You will also need to cater for leading/trailing dividers, which can easily be done with a couple of conditional checks.

Something like this:

```
var $contact = $('#contact-email');

$('.email').on('click', function () {
    var text = $(this).text(); // Get the value to insert/remove.
    var current = $contact.val(); // Get the current data.

    // Check if the value already exists with leading seperator, if so remove it.
    if (current.indexOf('; ' + text) > -1) {
        $contact.val(current.replace('; ' + text, ''));
    }
    // Check if the value already exists with trainling seperator, if so remove it.
    else if (current.indexOf(text + '; ') > -1) {
        $contact.val(current.replace(text + '; ', ''));
    }
    // Check if the value already exists with no seperator (on it's own), if so remove it.
    else if (current.indexOf(text) > -1) {
        $contact.val(current.replace(text, ''));
    } 
    // Otheriwse, it doesn't exist so add it.
    else {
        if (current) {
            $contact.val(current + '; ' + text);
        } else {
            $contact.val(text);
        }
    }
});
```

[Here is a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/ddwL365b/1)